# MYSQL Union initializes 0 and False as a bigint

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to union to tables together into a view but when the second table fills with (false or 0), it will convert the tinyint(1) into a bigint.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW people AS
SELECT 
    `id`, /*int*/
    `active` /*TINYINT(1)*/
FROM
    `table1` 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
    `id`, /*int*/
    0 AS `active` /* fill second column */
FROM
    `table2`
```

When I look at the fieldtype description it says

```
id     | int    | binary | 11 | 2  | 0 |
active | bigint | binary | 19 | 19 | 0 |
```

How can I get get the active (supposed to be bool/tinyint(1)) to stay the same data type after unioning?

Comment: The type of the column should not matter.  But MySQL does not have a way (to the best of my knowledge) to convert to a tinyint.

Comment: I'm syncing the database with the entity framework and it has to know the value types. It prevents me from comparing a long and a bool in the lambda function

Comment: Create not view but third table (use CREATE TABLE .. SELECT) then check for the datatypes.

Comment: Or create the table with your desired type, then use `INSERT INTO table SELECT ...`

Comment: Creating a new table isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

I just sent it in as null and when I checked it I returned false if it == null. basically giving me a 0/false constant return.